# Create a table with one column from a list of values as input to stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am receiving a list as input for a stored procedure in MySQL 5.6 and need to create a temporary table that has a a column (`listOfUsers`). Each item in the list, needs to be its own row for this column.

All the answers I've seen so far, show the list being used in a `WHERE` clause to filter a query. I am not trying to filter anything, just create a table with one column from a list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume some specifics in the example, I hope my assumptions are relevant to your problem. Suppose we have a comma-delimited list on one line in a file. Then we can do:

```
create table t1 (s varchar(50));
load data local infile '/tmp/file.txt' into table t1 
lines terminated by ',';
update t1 set s = replace(s, "\n", "");
```

The last update is needed to remove the spurious newline from the last column. Something based on this idea will hopefully solve your problem.

If the data is not coming from a file, a simple solution that requires minimum application coding is to put the data in a temporary file, and then apply the method above. Alternatively, you can just parse out the input in the application, and then build a multi-row insert.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not going to be coming from a file. Sorry for not specifying this. The list is going to be passed in the body of a POST API call.